# msi installer for wcf service

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-installer

Is it possible to create a msi installer to host WCF service on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wcf needs a host, be it a service or an IIS site, so you should either use a service installer or a web application installer.

Comment: I tried using web app installer, it doesn't seem to copy the .svc file. Is there a useful resource explaining for creating web app installer for WCF?

Comment: Check if you added "Content Files" as well as "Primary Output" in the "Add Project Output Group" dialog.